# Can I run a command from package.json bin script?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to run a command from a `bin` script in a `package.json` ? I know it expects a path to file and trying to run a command there results in an error upon installation (after publishing to npm). Is it possible to run a command like it is in an `npm start` ?

Examples:

```
{
  "name": "myscript",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "bin": {
    "myscript": "app/main.js"
  }
}
```

This will create a symlink from the `app/main.js` script to `/usr/local/bin/myscript`
Instead, this is what I want to achieve:

```
{
  "name": "myscript",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "bin": {
    "myscript": "echo hello world"
  }
}
```

Possible workarounds are also appreciated.

Comment: Not according to the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: Create a `.sh` file with the contents `echo hello world` and optionally add the header `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, any cross-platform similar solutions ? :)

Comment: @EvyatarMeged `echo` isn't cross-platform, so why should your bash file be?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, good point, but it was for example's sake.

Comment: Is there an example of a "cross platform shell command" then? If so I'd be happy to give a solution for how to run it.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is updated since the old answer was a bit dated and ultimately incorrect. You can now do:

```
npx myscript
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but upon publication of the package, will I be able to run it with an alias of my choosing (in my example, I just need to call `myscript` after installation). Seems like I'll have to specify the key in `scripts` as well ?

Comment: What command do I run if I have `"bin": "dist/src/cli.js",` in my package.json? I've been doing `node dist/src/cli.js` but is there a simpler command? Ideally something that runs `prepare` before running the script too, because I need to compile the TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `npm link` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link which would create a link to your binary, then you can just run your script on the command line as `myscript`.